# Why is my asterisk PBX not registering an extension but registers the sip lines from sip.provider.ca

Tags: asterisk, pbx

When making a call from a cellphone to the SIP external number 416XXXXXXX the call is going straight to the Ext voicemail, then to email. Call log shows the following:

```
[2015-06-02 13:52:49] WARNING[13331][C-00000003]: func_channel.c:538 func_channel_read: Unknown or unavailable item requested: 'reversecharge'
[2015-06-02 13:52:49] WARNING[13331][C-00000003]: app_dial.c:2437 dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type 'SIP' (cause 20 - Subscriber absent)
```

Looks like my extension to register even though the SIP provider number seems to register fine. If the SIP line registers but the extension doesn't, is there an obvious reason for this? Please help! Thx!

```
"
asterisk-CLI> sip show registry 
Host                    dnsmgr Username       Refresh State    Reg.Time                 
sip.provider.ca:5060    N      416XXXXXXX     105 Registered   Tue, 02 Jun 2015 12:27:17
"
```

```
asterisk-CLI> sip show peers
Name/username             Host          Dyn Forcerport Comedia    ACL Port     Status                            
288                       (Unspecified) D   Yes        Yes         A  0        UNKNOWN                                      
in_416xxxxxxx/416xxxxxxx  209.x.x.x         Yes        Yes            5060     OK (26 ms)                                   
out_416xxxxxxx/416xxxxxxx 209.x.x.x         Yes        Yes            5060     OK (26 ms)
```

Looking through the logs of the sip debug, it looks like the a problem with getting a CHANNEL extension to register.

cat debug_call_final | grep CHAN

```
"
-- Executing [416XXXXXXX@from-pstn:6] Set("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "CHANNEL(musicclass)=default") in new stack
-- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:34] Set("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "CHANNEL(language)=en") in new stack
-- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:33] ExecIf("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "1?Set(CHANNEL(musicclass)=default)") in new stack
-- Executing [s@macro-dial-one:47] GosubIf("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "0?s-CHANUNAVAIL,1()") in new stack
-- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:17] Set("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "SV_DIALSTATUS=CHANUNAVAIL") in new stack
-- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:20] Set("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "DIALSTATUS=CHANUNAVAIL") in new stack
-- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:22] GotoIf("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "0?s-CHANUNAVAIL,1") in new stack
-- Executing [s@macro-exten-vm:23] Macro("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "vm,288,CHANUNAVAIL,") in new stack
-- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:34] Set("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "CHANNEL(language)=en") in new stack
-- Executing [vmx@macro-vm:2] Set("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "MMODE=CHANUNAVAIL") in new stack
-- Executing [vmx@macro-vm:10] GotoIf("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "0?s-CHANUNAVAIL,1") in new stack
-- Executing [vmx@macro-vm:14] GotoIf("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "1?s-CHANUNAVAIL,1") in new stack
-- Goto (macro-vm,s-CHANUNAVAIL,1)
-- Executing [s-CHANUNAVAIL@macro-vm:1] Macro("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "get-vmcontext,288") in new stack
-- Executing [s-CHANUNAVAIL@macro-vm:2] VoiceMail("SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002", "288@default,u") in new stack
== Spawn extension (macro-vm, s-CHANUNAVAIL, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/in_416XXXXXXX-00000002' in macro 'vm'
"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(cause 20 - Subscriber absent)
```

This means your SIP phone that you are trying to send the call to is not connected to your Asterisk PBX.  Clearly the trunk is working properly, since you are getting the call.

Please post the configuration for the phone here so that we can take a look.  Also post the result of:

```
sip show peers
```

... at the PBX CLI.

Comment: So after going through the polycom 321 gui settings, I've managed to get the hard phone line registered, however the status is showing 'unreachable'. Ext 250 is a softphone registered through zoiper whereas ext 251 is a hardphone.